# ChefServer - Server returned error 502

Tags: linux, server, chef-infra, sles

I'm facing a problem during the Chef server configuration.
When I install Chef server for the first time, everything goes well. Now, since I need to do some tests, when I uninstall Chef server and I try to install it again and add a new user, this happens:

```
ERROR: Server returned error 502 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 1/5 in 4s
ERROR: Server returned error 502 for https://127.0.0.1/users/, retrying 2/5 in 5s
^C/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:218:in `system': Interrupt
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:218:in `run_command'
    from (eval):42:in `block (2 levels) in load_file'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:190:in `call'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:190:in `block in add_command_under_category'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.4.2/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:661:in `run'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:192:in `<main>'
```

Probably is also worth to mention, that when I remove Chef server, I do:

```
chef-server-ctl uninstall
rm -rf /etc/chef
rm -rf /etc/opscode
rm -rf /opt/opscode
rpm -e chef-server-core-12.2.0-1.el5
```

I'm using SLES 11 SP1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you run chef-server-ctl reconfigure after installing it?

Comment: yes, but I want to deinstall it. I have found the answer by trying several things.

Comment: May I ask why you reinstall install of using `chef-server-ctl cleanse` which return in fresh install state ?

Comment: I'm doing a script to automate chef server installation so I had to do it from the beginning all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to uninstall Chef completely and also be able to install it successfully:

```
chef-server-ctl uninstall
rpm -qa | grep chef
rpm -e chef-server-12.2.1-pipapo
rm -rf /root/.chef
rm -rf /etc/opscode
rm -rf /opt/opscode
rm -rf /var/opt/opscode
rcapache2 restart
```

At this point if you want to add a user or do a `chef-server-ctl test` you might receive an error like:

```
ERROR: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
```

To fix this, restart apache2 again and retry.

I hope it helps you!